# Google translate API: cannot send more than 2000 characters per request

Tags: google-translate

The Google translate API FAQ at https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/faq#technical states that the maximum number of characters per request is 5000. However, I am unable to send more than 2000 characters without getting HTTP error 414: The requested URL /translate... is too large to process.

I am getting this from my .NET app but have also reproduced the same error from Fiddler.

Below is the URL I am sending (just over 2000 characters). Am I misunderstanding the 5000 character limit?

https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=MYKEY-MYKEY-MYKEY-MYKEY-MYKEY-MYKEY-KEY&source=en&target=es&q=From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0AIf%20traveling%20to%20the%20west%20From%20Sparta%3A%0D%0A

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to POST the data if you wish to process more than 2000 characters:

> All other query parameters are optional. The URL for the GET,
>   including parameters, **must be less than 2K characters**.
>
> Note: You can also use POST to invoke the API if you want to send more
>   data in a single request

https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest